# How to disable popups with code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, popup

When using left mouse button + Ctrl on a method and navigating to it (maybe in another file), an annoying yellow popup with code appears and obscures the toolbar:

[image]

How to disable it? I've searched in the settings and the internet, but found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like restarting Android Studio helped